# Can I publish another site's image as it is mine with htaccess mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know question seems little scamy but I couldn't find a better way to ask.

I have few websites and there are lot of images that are common. So I decided to publish common files from one source not to use more disc space. But I also don't want visitors to know it and want to show all contents publishing from own domain.

Can I get an image from http://domain2.com/image.jpg by requesting http://domain1.com/image.jpg ? I tried some combinations but couldn't succeed!

Thank you!

Comment: uhm, why shouldn't it be possible for the user to see that? static content server or a CDN are absolute normal - in any case, you could make a file System Mount between your servers, or proxy it

Comment: I don't want the relation known public, that's why. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the resources are in the same place, you can easily configure your web server to serve from different locations, for example, Apache's virtual host configuration should like something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/path/to/images
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

*Update* based on additional information

If you want images to be served from `domain1.com/images` and `domain2.com/images`, you can do it in two ways.

1) Create two virtual hosts with aliases towards the same image folder:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     DocumentRoot /var/path/to/domain1.com/files
>     ServerName domain1.com
>     Alias /images/ /var/path/to/images
> </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     DocumentRoot /var/path/to/domain2.com/files
>     ServerName domain2.com
>     Alias /images/ /var/path/to/images
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

2) Create a symlink, for example:

> $ ln -s /var/path/to/images /var/path/to/domain1.com/files
>
> $ ln -s /var/path/to/images /var/path/to/domain2.com/files

You are mapping the same location in both above cases, it's just a different approach.

Comment: What if directories are different? For example can I get http://www.domain2.com/images/image.jpg over http://www.domain2.com/image.jpg

Comment: Not sure I understand, you want them accessible via both URLs or just one?

Comment: They should be accessible from all domains but I can serve all static content from a seperate domain if there is no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to route the image requests to a php file which knows how to map the request to the correct url, and then send the correct http header and include the image.

Comment: Are you suggesting using reading image with file_get_contents and echoing with a image header?

Comment: correct (if David Kuridža solution is not feasible for you). You could add some sort of file cache to reduce cross-domain traffic.

Comment: Even though this solutions work, it would create an additional overload. Unless you solve a specific problem with it, I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: Yeah. I also don't want server load for disk space.

Comment: It's more a solution for people who don't have the option to change their server config.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that domain1.com and domain2.com are on the same local network, then rather than using mod-rewrite, I would suggest creating symlinks to the shared image folders, so that they are accessible in each of your sites as if they were a local directory. You'll need to enable symlinks in your htaccess file for this to work, but it's a lot less hassle than using mod-rewrite for this.

If they're not on the same network, then a mod-rewrite with a 301 redirect to the same filename on the alternative domain should do the trick.

The other thing worth mentioning is that often it can be good practice to serve images from a second domain name. If you go to Yahoo, for example, you'll find that their images are served from subdomains of `yimg.com` even though you've navigated to yahoo.com. This is good practice for performance tuning a site, because both browsers and web servers have limits on the number of files they can download concurrently from the same domain, so splitting the requests on a single page between multiple domains allows more files to be served concurrently and reduces the load on each server. Therefore, your best option may be to put the images into a central location where they can be served for all your domains, under their own domain.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Spudley. Domains are on same network now but if I could do this I am planning to move static contents to a cheaper host. It would be like your 3rd paragraph.  Thank you.